# NSMutableArray swap objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want to swap objects in a NSMutableArray. I use a normal way to swap:

```
NSMutableArray* arr = ...; //- really means mutable; //- or converted from [NSArray mutableCopy]

Item* item0 = arr[0];
Item* item1 = arr[1];
Item* bk;

bk = item0;
item0 = item1;
item1 = bk;
```

The above code doesn't work, the array is still the same. I know the solution is use :

```
[arr exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:1];
```

The question here is why my code doesn't work ??? Thanks.

***Sorry, my code is correct 100%. So we can use either my code or Apple code. Thanks***

Answer (score 0):

You just swapped the positions in your local variables, not in the actual array. What the pointers point to in your local context has been changed but the contents of the array is still the same.

Comment: What do you do with other languages like Java or C ? The above code (my code) is for all languages? NO?

Comment: It totally depends on the language but the above code neither in Java or C would change contents of the array it is using the elements from.

Comment: It's not convinced me so much. The array is just a set of pointers. When you change the pointer of each element, the content will be changed.

Comment: The array _is_ a set of pointers, but it is not the pointers in the array you are changing with your code.

Comment: I changed the pointer of an item in the array, not change the pointer of the array.